# Как выйти из функции?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

пишу бота для телеграмм на python 3 и столкнулся с такой проблемой, когда прописываешь команду /echo включается функция эхо как и планируется, но когда пишешь другую команду где тоже нужен ввод слов ехо не отключается. Прошу помогите

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['echo'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Функция эхо включена")
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def send_echo(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы не указали какую библиотеку используете (предполагаю что pyTelegramBotAPI).
2. Вы используете декоратор в декораторе. В данном случае это ошибка. Попробуйте, вот так:

```py
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['echo'])
    def start(message):
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Функция эхо включена")
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def send_echo(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
```

Comment: в вашем случае по команде будет только появляться сообщение, а эхо будет постоянно